# Add html's src inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML code that has only one line of code:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=ID"></script>
```

But I do not want to use HTML at all. Since I am performing all my functions inside my javascript, can I add the above code inside my JavaScript? If so, how?

```
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'ID');
```

Comment: If you don't want to use HTML at all, how will you execute the JS file in your users browser?

Comment: HTML is a fundamental part of the web. What purpose does this page server?

Comment: Simply writing `<script src="/site.js"></script>` on every page means that you don't need to reuse as much code. For example, if you wanted to change the ID (and you weren't using any fancy server-side code), you would have to go through every page to do so.

Comment: Yes HTML is required to load a webpage. I understand that and although I am using HTML with javascript, I just wanted to know if there is a way to add an html code to load a javascript inside another javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own rhetorical question, there is a way to append url inside my javascript by this way:

```
function appendScript(){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=ID"; 
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}

appendScript();
```